# how do i delete variables in order to reuse them in java

Tags: java

I am making a calculator that theoretically should be able to go over the normal integer limit right now I am prototyping a smaller test version of this thing. I often have to often carry a number like in multiplication but I use the same variable over and over again and I want to be able to clear those variables in order to reuse them in my calculator

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.LinkedList ;
public class mass_mulitplication_software {
public static void multiply () {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);


    //multiplication#1
    System.out.println("ones place");
    double fnum1 = keyboard.nextDouble() ; 
    System.out.println("tens place");
    double fnum2 = keyboard.nextDouble() ; 
    System.out.println("hundreds place");
    double fnum3 = keyboard.nextDouble() ;
    //multiplication#2


    System.out.println("ones place");
    double snum1 = keyboard.nextDouble() ; 
    System.out.println("tens place");
    double snum2 = keyboard.nextDouble() ; 
    System.out.println("hundreds place");
    double snum3 = keyboard.nextDouble() ;

    tnum=fnum1*snum1;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();

    tnum=fnum1*snum2;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();
    tnum=fnum1*snum3;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();
    tnum=fnum2*snum1;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();
    tnum=fnum2*snum2;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();               
    tnum=fnum2*snum3;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();
    tnum=fnum3*snum1;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();
    tnum=fnum3*snum2;
    mass_mulitplication_software.carry();
    tnum=fnum3*snum3;
    }   

  public static double carry(){
    if (tnum>10){
    double mnum= tnum%10;
    double mmnum = tnum- mnum ;
    double cnum = mmnum/10 ;
    return cnum;}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    mass_mulitplication_software.multiply();
}   }
```

also please consider I am a novice coder who has just begun coding and wished to improve upon my old calculator to take bigger numbers this a small version prototype for multiplying specifically do any of u guys know how to clear a double variable so it can be reused with a different #

Comment: Why not just use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: What do you mean by clearing? Normally you can reuse a variable as often as you want to. You can also just assign 0 to it, like tnum = 0. Or simply use BigInteger like JackVanier suggests, this would be the simpler solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previous commentor's said consider using BigInteger or unsigned int. And put each input into its own variable, it will make your life a lot easier, and you wont need the `carry()` method.

Aside from that, a few things to point out, you call the `carry()` method, but do nothing with the double that it returns, also in this case, `tnum` will always equal `fnum3 * snum3`

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a menu with an option to clear all numbers, and upon choosing that option, have a method that sets those variables to 0. This menu would go in the main method.

It seems like you might want to have a menu using a while loop regardless, so you can repeat this process over and over again with different values.

something like:

```
int menuChoice = -1;

        while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 8) {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Menu");
            System.out.println("1. Add");
            System.out.println("2. Subtract");
            System.out.println("3. Multiply");
            System.out.println("4. Divide");
            System.out.println("5. Power");
            System.out.println("6. Logarithm");
            System.out.println("7. Clear");
            System.out.println("8. Quit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");

            menuChoice = input.nextInt();

            if (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 8) {
                System.out.println(menuChoice + " wasn't one of the options");
            }
        }

        return menuChoice;
}
```

This is the menu from a calculator I'm working on. You can use if statements to perform appropriate functions based on what the user enters. So you could have a menu option to multiply, and have the user enter values into each variable for your numbers.

You don't actually have to clear variables--after a function is performed, the menu would simply display again after the operation is performed, since menuChoice is initialized to -1 before the while loop. The user would just choose an option and enter new values into those variables which would replace the old ones.

You might simply want to use unsigned long long int as your variable type, since it's range is from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. The method you're using seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an array to store the digits of your variables, rather than trying to hold all the digits in individual variables. This will make it easier for you to iterate over them when you do your `carry()` and `borrow()` operations, since those may need to move values up and down the length of your digits.

You could then, say, do multiplication and division the way you would long-hand, using an array to store intermediate values. Consider:

```
public class Digits {
    List<Integer> digits;

    public Digits() {
        digits = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Digits(Digits other) {
        digits = other.getDigits();
    }

    public List<Integer> getDigits() {
        return digits;
    }

    public Digits times(Digits other) {
        List<Integer> newDigits = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<other.getDigits().size(); i++) {
            for (int j=0; j< digits.size(); j++) {
                Integer temp;
                try {
                    temp = newDigits.get(i+j);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
                    temp = 0;
                }
                newDigits.set(i+j, temp + other.getDigits().get(i) * digits.get(j));
            }
            carry();
        }
    }

    private void carry() {
        for (int i=0; i<digits.size(); i++) {
            while (digits.get(i) >= 10) {
                digits.set(i, digits.get(i) - 10);
                digits.set(i+1, digits.get(i+1) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```